# OpenGL RGB DXT1 compressed texture mipmap upload

Tags: c++, opengl, compression, textures, mipmaps

I'm trying to upload GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT format mipmaped texture levels using PBO.
the program is resizing and compressing the images using the `stb_resize.h` and `stb_dxt.h` libraries.

Apparently the image compression works okay, but uploading any *mipmap levels* produces following result:
[image: Broken Mipmaped texture render]

However If I define no mipmap levels for the texture it renders correcly.
Also I'm not getting *any* errors from OpenGL as I have `GL_KHR_debug` enabled.

Here is the opengl code for uploading mipmaps, with some of my own library code in between:

```
// Load image:
auto img = loadImage2D("parrot.png");

// Resize the image to power-of-two
int max_mipmaps = 1;
unsigned int max_size = nextPow2(std::max(img.width, img.height));
for(int i = max_size; i > 4; i >>= 1)
    max_mipmaps++;

auto rimg = img.scaleCubic(max_size,max_size);

// Allocate PBO to source compressed mipmap levels from
handle_t pbo;
size_t pbosize = rimg.compressed_size();
glCreateBuffers(1, &pbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glBufferStorage(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbosize, 0,
    GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT|GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT|GL_MAP_READ_BIT|GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT);
// Map the buffer
void * pbodata = (char*)glMapBufferRange(
    GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0, pbosize,
    GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT|GL_MAP_READ_BIT
    |GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT
    |GL_MAP_FLUSH_EXPLICIT_BIT);

// Compress the image and write the data directly into PBO.
// compress_to() fmt returns GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT
option_t fmt;
rimg.compress_to(pbodata, fmt);
glFlushMappedBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0, pbosize);

// Allocate the texture
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTextureStorage2D(texture, max_mipmaps, fmt, rimg.width, rimg.width);
// Upload base image level.
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glCompressedTextureSubImage2D(texture, 0, 0,0, rimg.width, rimg.height, fmt, rimg.compressed_size(), 0);
// Process and Upload mipmap levels.
unsigned int mipmapsize = max_size >> 1;
for(int i = 1; i < max_mipmaps && mipmapsize >= 4; ++i) {
    // Resize next mipmap level.
    rimg = img.scaleLinear(mipmapsize,mipmapsize);

    // Compress the image and write result to *pbodata
    rimg.compress_to(pbodata, fmt);
    glFlushMappedBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0, pbosize);

    // Upload mipmap image level.
    glCompressedTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, 0,0, rimg.width, rimg.height, fmt, rimg.compressed_size(), 0);

    mipmapsize >>= 1;
}
// Discard the PBO
glUnmapNamedBuffer(pbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER,0);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &pbo);

// Set texture params.
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, max_mipmaps - 1);
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `glFlushMappedBufferRange` will **not** be sufficient to ensure proper synchronization with the GPU. And this is what seems to be happening here: the whole mipmap pyramid is created on the CPU, *before* the GPU processes the first `glCompressedTexSubImage2D` call.

As a quick&dirty test for this hypothesis, you can add a `glFinish` into the loop. To properly synchronize it, you could use [GL Sync Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sync_Object), but it would be best if you avoided any need to synchronize at all: just use a PBO which is big enough to hold the whole mipmap pyramid data.

Comment: I had small suspect that CPU is overwriting the data too soon before glCompressedTexSubImage2D() can acquire it. *thank you*
PS: Can I simply use new fresh PBOs for each texture level upload and then just discard the PBOs after last gl*TexSubImage2D call?

Comment: Yes, you can of course use multiple PBOs here, too. What the best option is performance wise, is most likely using just one PBO with different ranges, and create and map it just once. OTOH, the CPU-side DXT compression and image scale operations will probably be the limiting factor here anyway...